# Creating an FFmpeg image slideshow with zoompan and fade in/out

Tags: ffmpeg

I've been trying FFmpeg through whatever tutorials I can find over the internet and I'm a bit puzzled as to how to combine a zoompan effect with fade in and fade out of a series of images.

A got to the following after combining bits and pieces of examples I found but it looks like the result I get is sequential and not what I thought it would be.

Any pointers to point me to the right direction would be appreciated.

```
ffmpeg \ 
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input/slideshow/img0001.jpeg 
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input/slideshow/img0002.jpeg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input/slideshow/img0003.jpeg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input/slideshow/img0004.jpeg \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v0]; \
 [1:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v1]; \
 [2:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v2]; \
 [3:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v3]; \
 [v0][v1][v2][v3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -s "800x450" -t 40 output/out_fade.mp4
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve versus what you actually achieved, can you clarify? A gif would be very handy!

Comment: Hi @bertieb thanks for your reply. My goal is to create a command with an arbitrary number of pictures which will appear in sequence with a fade in and out and each one will zoom in for the time that is visible. So let's say i have 4 images like above, first one starts off the video and it's zooming out and at the end of the 5 seconds fades out while the second one fades in already zoomed in and continues with the same zoom out and so on to the third and fourth. Been messing around with it some more after I posted the question, it looks like I haven't quite grasped the ffmpeg usage

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It sounds like the effect would approximate a 'continuous' (albeit over different images) zoom-out if I've understood correctly?

Comment: more or less yes, actually the ultimate goal would be to have random ways of presenting the images of the slideshow I started by trying a fadein fadeout which worked ok and moving on I tried the zoompan as well to add a bit of movement before the transition from one to the other ... maybe the next step would be to have the images sliding over the previous one.

Comment: Okay, it sounds like you're wanting to go beyond the scope of the original question (*'how do I combine a zoompan with fade out in `ffmpeg`?'*, which is answerable); to something more generic which may not be easily answerable. I would recommend looking at a tool or library which automates these kinds of transitions, just as the MLT framework.

Comment: I am taking it step by step :) and the thing is I want to collect whatever I can do with ffmpeg because the whole thing will be set up as a web app project and it will have to be able to work through the ffmpeg cli. Could you suggest anything on the original question asked? thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Combining a zoom with a fade with `ffmpeg`

The example you gave with `ffmpeg` actually worked with very little modification (keeping `-loop` in caused a segfault: "`Error in 'ffmpeg': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000000008dffa00`").

So we have:

```
ffmpeg \
-t 5 -i 1.jpg \
-t 5 -i 2.jpg \
-t 5 -i 3.jpg \
-t 5 -i 4.jpg \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v0]; \
 [1:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v1]; \
 [2:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v2]; \
 [3:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v3]; \
 [v0][v1][v2][v3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -s "800x450" -t 40 ./out_fade.mp4
```

### Example Output:

[image: zoompan and fade example]

*Potato quality- I need to figure out `gif` optimisation better! Artifacts and distortion are result of trying to get file size < 2MB and are not present in original video output- it should be enough to give you an idea of whether it fits your use-case. Images are my own.*

---

## *(additional)* Using varied or arbitrary transitions

*added based on comments*

Even with this minimal example, the `filtergraph` gets quite complex quite quickly, and it's tedious to change things. A different library might do better.

### MLT / MELT

For example,[`MELT` for the MLT Framework](https://www.mltframework.org/docs/melt/) might do:

> Melt was developed as a test tool for the MLT framework. It can be thought of as a powerful, if somewhat obscure, multitrack command line oriented video editor.

and is frequently suggested.

### MoviePy

However, [MoviePy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) (GitHub page) might suit your needs better, as it is slightly more concise and (I'd suggest) more user-friendly, insofar as a command-line video editor can be user-friendly.

You probably are most interested in the sections on [compositing](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/compositing.html) and [transitions/effects](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/effects.html)

---

I suggest the above two based on my own experience of trying to crowbar in transitions with `ffmpeg`; it's doable and capable of producing some very decent effects, but the pain is not worth it. The script above should answer your question about a continuous zoom-out with a fade in/out.

Comment: I was looking for hours for that you save my life literally .

Comment: @bertieb This effect is working fine with only Landscape video and for square & portrait Images the video is playing in landscape

`-t 10 -i img00.jpg -t 10 -i img01.jpg -filter_complex [0:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.7,max(1.001,zoom-0.0045))':d=125,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v0];[1:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.7,max(1.001,zoom-0.0045))':d=125,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v1];[v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v] -map [v] -s 720x1280 -t 40 -preset ultrafast video25.mp4`

Comment: Here for zoom in and out from center : https://superuser.com/a/1112737/860920